# Powershell Script to search a file and then send an email

Tags: powershell

I am new to **Powershell**

I am creating a file with output in it and then search that file for a specific phrase and if it contains it, get sent an email. I've been able to create the file and then filter out what I need using sls but I can't seem to figure out how to get that file sent to me via email **if** it contains a specific word.

Ex - If the file contains the word **Offline** send that file attached to an email.

These are the following commands I've run so far -

```
d:
set-location -Path "program files\veritas\volmgr\bin"
.\vmoprcmd >d:\test.data\mediastatus.txt
cd \
set-location -Path "test.data"
sls offline .\mediastatus.txt
```

Comment: Show what work you've done and you're more likely to get assistance.

Comment: You can likely simplify your commands to just `"D:\program files\veritas\volmgr\bin\vmoprcmd" >D:\test.data\mediastatus.txt` and
`sls offline D:\test.data\mediastatus.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your situation-

- you have output that's generated by this `vmoprcmd` executable
- it's redirected to a file
- you want to detect whether the file/output contains the string `"Offline"`
- if it does, trigger an email

To achieve this, you can utilize the `Select-String` and `Send-MailMessage` cmdlets:

```
$Output = 'D:\test.data\mediastatus.txt'
& 'D:\Program Files\veritas\volmgr\bin\vmoprcmd.exe' > $Output

if (Select-String -Pattern offline -Path $Output -Quiet) {
    $MailArgs = @{
        'To'          = 'mailaddress@example.com'
        'From'        = 'mymailbot@example.com'
        'Subject'     = 'Device offline!'
        'Attachments' = $Output
        'Body'        = 'Whatever you want it to be'

        'SmtpServer'  = 'my.smtp.server.com'
        'Port'        = 25
    }
    Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
}
```

Documentation:

- [Call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators)
- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`@Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: THIS WORKED!! THANK YOU!

Comment: @AB2112 Glad to be of service.  If this solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer ✅